# Can't get Quarto to produce a full width page

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

Quarto's setup is really wasteful with space having two really wide margins left and right. How can I increase the width of the page? It currently uses what looks like a 20:60:20 split. I'm using Quarto 1.2.280. I've tried altering the page-layout but to no effect. I'm trying to run this as presentation on a web page.

```
format:
  revealjs:
    incremental: false
    theme: moon
    footer: "Slurm walk-through"
    logo: RSG.png
    css: logo.css
    fig-cap-location: margin
    code-line-numbers: true
    fontsize: 30px
    page-layout: full
---
```

Comment: check out the [presentation size](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/advanced.html#presentation-size) section from Quarto revealjs docs. And also I would recommend updating to Quarto version 1.3!

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add the width parameter to the format block. Simple and I only found it after after the question.

```
format:
  revealjs:
    width: 1500
    incremental: false
    theme: moon
    footer: "Slurm walk-through"
    logo: RSG.png
    css: logo.css
    fig-cap-location: margin
    code-line-numbers: true
    fontsize: 30px
    page-layout: full
---
```